# Is it possible, perhaps with Apple's permission, to switch an app to the foreground without user input?

Tags: ios, iphone

We would like to be able to remotely control an app on an iOS device so that the app can be automatically brought to the foreground WITHOUT the user having to do anything, for example when the app receives a remote push notification.  My understanding is that normally there is no way to bring an app to the foreground in iOS unless the user presses a button, because Apple has decided that it knows best, and that it is better for app developers and users not to have this possibility, because it could be abused.

We are working on a security-related app where we believe that there would be strong justification for this type of functionality (in a case where the user is not able to take any actions).

Two questions:

1. Is there any way to do this in iOS coding that others on similar posts have overlooked?
2. Does anyone have experience with whether Apple ever grants exceptions to this kind of rule if there is a good justification?

Comment: I honestly hope there's no way of doing it, at least, not without a user giving your specific app an explicit permission to do such remotely controlled "popup ads" :-).

Comment: It would be wonderful if users could opt-in to control over their own device without jailbreaking.  Having 'opt-in' control over ANY function of the phone (which the user paid for) would be quite reasonable... certainly any feature that would only affect usability and not more challenging things like network security, device hardware, etc.  While I appreciate that this kind of function could be abused by app developers, especially for unsophisticated users, I really think that the relationship between a user and the software that THEY choose to install should be THEIR choice, not Apple's.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: NO, and there is no chance that Apple will agree to allow you to implement such functionality. The only app that does this is the Phone.app because that is its purpose.